# Why do sketches take up so much space and memory in arduino?

Tags: arduino, iot, arduino-uno

When I compile my program i get this message

Sketch uses 7,074 bytes (21%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 1,033 bytes (50%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,015 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

What do this message states?

this is my code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    SPI.begin();            // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
    Serial.println("Scan PICC to see UID and type...");
}

void loop() {
    // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;//go to start of loop if there is no card present
    }

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;//if ReadCardSerial returns 1, the "uid" struct (see MFRC522.h lines 238-45)) contains the ID of the read card.
    }

    // Dump debug info about the card. PICC_HaltA() is automatically called.
    mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
```

and I'm getting this message on blinking led long pin 13 too

Comment: Not easy to say without seeing code. However big program memory usage is price for Arduino framework "genericity". Huge `RAM` usage might be caused by string literals without using `_FlashStringHelper` and `F("literals")`. And some of that is used by Arduino Framework (a far as I remember, it's about 200B).

Comment: have uploaded the code

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807871/arduino-is-the-command-serial-printsome-string-text-occupying-sram/12808969#12808969) you'll see that without care, constant strings like "Scan PICC to see UID and type..." will use SRAM (dynamic memory) and not flash (program storage space).

Answer (score -1):

It is a message that informs you on the state of arduino's memory.

Comment: okay. so its not an error and nor will it effect the working?